# is there such things as Quantum Operating system?

Tags: programming

Wikipedia informed me about quite a lot of language that exist for quantum computing, with diverse low or high level language, but I don't know about specific operating system made for specific architecture of quantum computers.

Are we at the same level of development of the (personnal) computer's themselves in the 70/80's where every brand has his own language, instruction set and chipset ? or is there something like a posix for QC ?

Comment: please inform me of appropriate tag to use for this question, <3, thanks

Comment: A useful analogy is comparing quantum computers with Graphical processing units (GPUs). GPUs don't usually run operating systems. They are co-processors to CPUs. A classical computer that's specially purposed to interact well with a quantum computer (efficiently sending control signals to the quantum chip e.t.c) could be called a Quantum OS but I'm assuming you mean running an OS on a quantum processor; which is impractical.

Comment: Just note that classical computers were at such level of development in 50's or early 60's. In 70/80's as you wrote, much standardisation has just taken place.  Overall, nice question, +1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There does exist the so-called quantum operating system, for example, [this one](https://www.rayradar.com/2021/02/08/benyuan-quantum-releases-benyuan-sinan-the-first-quantum-computer-operating-system-in-china/). But I don't think you can compare the process of a quantum computer with a classical computer. At least for now, I think the best hope is to build a quantum computer that can offer quantum computing services in the style of cloud computing, while universal quantum computers might really be very far from us.